# Convert str to char* issue

Tags: c++, string, qt, char, qstring

I need to convert a Str to char* but I sometimes lose a part of the string.

For example:

```
str:  "/Users/seb/Pictures/Photos/20141009 - Aulani - Hawaii/20141009_083318_Richtone(HDR).jpg"
char*:  /Users/seb/Pictures/Photos/20141009 - Aulani - Hawaii/20141009_083318_Ri
```

I'm using the code below:

```
void TreeWidget::CopyFilesFromLocal(QStringList pathList, QTreeWidgetItem * item) {
    QString fileelt;
    uint32_t Folder_id = INVALID;

    MyTreeWidget* myItem = dynamic_cast<MyTreeWidget*>(item);

    uint32_t destination_id = myItem->mtp_item_id;

    item->setExpanded(true);
    qDebug() << "**************************************";
    qDebug() << "Send to PULS Start";
    qDebug() << "Start of Loop to copy files";

    foreach(fileelt, pathList) {
        char *txt = NULL;
     //   char *isFileName = NULL;
        qDebug() << "str: " << fileelt;
        txt = strdup(m_device.convertQStr2char(fileelt));
        qDebug() << "char*: " << txt;
```

Here is the api I use.

```
char *PulsDeviceMngr::convertQStr2char(QString str) {
    return const_cast<char*>(std::string(str.toUtf8().constData() ).c_str());
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: When you say `Str`, do you mean [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) or [`QString`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html)? Not that it really matters as both have very well-documented functions to get `const char*` to the contained strings.

Comment: I mean Qstring. I'm mostly using it for QString.

Comment: Is there any diff if it's a std:string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer you return form `convertQStr2char` points to the internal buffer of the temporary `std::string` which is destroyed after the `return`. You thus use a dangling pointer and have undefined behavior.

Note that changing the data pointed to by `std::string::c_string()` through said pointer also is UB. Your `const_cast` is a very bad idea because it would allow exactly this even if you got the lifetime right.

You could do this instead (includes a couple of unnecessary copies, but get it working first, then worry about the rest):

```
char *PulsDeviceMngr::convertQStr2char(QString str) {
    return strdup(std::string(str.toUtf8().constData() ).c_str());
}
```

Then do not forget to `free` the buffer. But it would probably be better to just return the `std::string` by value and then use `.c_str()` outside of your conversion function. This way, you do not need to use the non-C++ `strdup` and do not need to manage memory by hand, which would be error prone anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra method

```
txt = strdup(fileelt.toUtf8().constData());
```

will work fine.